# Is there an elegant way to write specific query in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]I have three tables: INVENTORY, TRANSFER, INVENTORY_TRANSFER.

Transfers can have three states: ACCEPTED, PENDING, DECLINED.

If transfer has status 'ACCEPTED' or 'DECLINED' the inventory can be transferred again. It means we can create a new row in TRANSFER. And 
create a raw in INVENTORY_TRANSFER and assign in it inventory id and transfer id

So I need to get all inventory, which wasn't transferred or the last transfer(inventory_transfer with the largest id) with this inventory has status 'ACCEPTED' or 'DECLINED'.

If inventory wasn't transferred it means there are not records in inventory_transfer with specific inventory and transfer

So, i understand that i need to do

```sql
SELECT * FROM INVENTORY i 
LEFT JOIN INVENTORY_TRANSFER it on i.inventory_id = it.invetory_id
LEFT JOIN TRANSFER t on it.transfer_id = t.transfer_id
WHERE ???
```

Is there elegant way to get inventory where the last transfer with inventory has not 'PENDING' status.

Comment: could u please provide sample data and your expected output in table format?/

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: what do you mean with " last transfer with inventory" .? ..  is not clear

Comment: Can you use something like [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4) to set up some sample data so we can understand the structure, and please also show us the result you would expect from that sample. It's quite hard to answer questions like this in the abstract without data. Don't forget, we may know about SQL in general but we do not understand your specific data model or business requirements necessarily.

Comment: Also, in "last transfer with inventory", please define "last"...is it by date? Is there a specific date field we should use? or by ID? And presumably "wasn't transferred" means there is no record in the transfer table at all for that item? Or could there be a record there but with a specific status? Again, we don't understand your data model. Please be clear and specific about your requirements. Try and describe it in terms of the fields in the table, rather than your business terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can find the last transfer record using `distinct on` and then find whether that matches your condition:

```
select i.*
from inventory i left join
     (select distinct on (it.inventory_id) it.inventory_id, t.status
      from inventory_transfer it join
           transfer t
           on it.transfer_id = t.transfer_id
      order by it.inventory_id, it.created_datetime desc
     ) it
     on it.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
where it.inventory_id is null or  -- no transfers 
      it.status in ('ACCEPTED', 'DECLINED');
```

This uses the created timestamp to determine the "last" record.  Your question is unclear on whether this should be the created or updated timestamp.